# How to Check Intent already launched?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, singleton, android-lifecycle

I am launching one Activity and resuming that activity from background , therefore how can I know that activity is already launched and still active. When putting the application in background, Activity gets stop but when resuming the application from background to foreground, how will I know that it is already there and no need to recreate the instance of same Intent.

```
public static void launchMyActivty() {

Log.d("isActivity Available", ""+MySingleton.isActivityAvailable(masterAct, "com.mypackage", "com.mypackage.ui.Activity"));     // Always returns true becuase activity is defined in Manifest
Log.d("isIntent Available", ""+MySingleton.isIntentAvailable(masterAct, "com.mypackage.android.ENCODE"));         //  Always returns false, I dont know why

            Intent myintent = masterAct.getIntent();
            String encodeCheck = myintent.getStringExtra("ENCODE_DATA");     //// returning null everytime

            ///  com.mypackage.ui.Activity            ///   This is not Default Activity


            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName("com.mypackage","com.mypackage.ui.Activity");

            if (masterAct.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent,
                       PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null) {

              Log.d("Already launched", "Already launched");     // This is always called even for the first time.

        } else {

                         Log.d("Launching for first time", "Launching for first time");  
                      ///This is never called

                        if (encodeCheck == null) {


                          intent.setAction("com.mypackage.android.ENCODE");
                          intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE");
                          intent.putExtra ("ENCODE_DATA", "123456789");
                          //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                           masterAct.startActivity(intent);

                        }
        }


 }
```

Please make sure that my Activity is not Default or Main Activity , it is sub activity.

Also the method from Singleton to check

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List resolveInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    Log.d("List Actions", ""+resolveInfo);

    if (resolveInfo.size() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public static boolean isActivityAvailable(Context context, String packageName,
        String className) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName(packageName, className);

    List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    return list.size() > 0;
}


public boolean isCallable() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings.ethernet",
            "com.android.settings.ethernet.EthernetSettingsAML");

    if (getActivity().getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you need is to have only one instance of the activity running, what you can do is to add to the activity declaration in the manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

which...

> A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task. If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a different task

Comment: No I need to check already launched instance from code as I am dumping data on that launched and for second time I dont want to dump data.

Comment: and the moment I define launchMode in Manifest for that activity , so it takes me to parent screen on calling finish or onBackButton pressed so have to remove that and need to handle it with code.

Answer (score 0):

I did I quick work around and in order to avoid memory leaks as

```
//where masterAct is static variable to MasterView.this
//and androAct is static variable define in MyActivity class as MyActivity.this

                                            if (MyActivity.androAct != null){
                                                MyActivity.androAct.finish();
                                            }


                                            //Intent intent = new Intent(masterAct, MyActivity.class);
                                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                                            intent.setClassName(
                                                    "org.mypackage",
                                                    "org.mypackage.ui.MyActivity");

                                                    intent.setAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
                                                intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE");
                                                intent.putExtra ("ENCODE_DATA", "123456789");
                                                //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                                                masterAct.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is still not the right way for checking already launched activities, Do I need to maintain an Array? for that